# For which of the following values of real number $t$, the equation $x^4-tx+\dfrac 1t = 0$ has no root on the interval $[1,2]$.

Tags: parametric

For which of the following values of real number $t$, the equation $x^4-tx+\dfrac 1t = 0$ has no root on the interval $[1,2]$.
I think we might check for which $t$ $y=tx-\dfrac 1t $  have solution on [1,16].

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=x^4-tx+\frac{1}{t}$?

Comment: No, I mean f(x)=tx-1/t on [1;16]

Comment: How to solve this?